# Promotion exchange for websites?

Tags: advertising, website-promotion

I've seen "AdDuplex" for windows phone, which basically advertises participating apps inside other apps and vice versa.

I like this concept and am wondering, if there is something similar for websites. I've been searching for a while and couldn't find anything, does someone of you?

Answer (score 0):

There're a lot of websites that propose link exchange. A simple search on Google will show you a bunch of them. Anyway, one of this is [www.linkpartners.com](http://www.linkpartners.com/)